# Странно сортируется массив в PowerShell

Tags: массивы, windows, сортировка, powershell

У меня проблема - очень странно сортирует массив.
Код:

```
$al = @('а','б','в','г','д','е','ё','ж','з','и','й','к','л','м','н','о','п','р','с','т','у','ф','х','ц','ч','ш','щ','ъ','ы','ь','э','ю','я')

function Get-Key{
    $arr =  [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
    $key = @{}
    $k = 0

    for($i=0;$i-lt33;$i++){
        $code = Get-Random -Minimum 100 -Maximum 5000
        $null = $arr.Add([char]$code)
    }

    foreach($j in $al){
        $key.Add($j, $arr[$k])
        $k++
        Write-Output "$j $k ${arr[$k]}"
    }

    ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $key | Set-Content "./key.json" -Encoding UTF8
}
```

Однако буквы в JSON-файле расположены неправильно.

Comment: Слов "что-то работает неправильно" недостаточно. Пишите в вопросе: 1) что вы ожидали получить, 2) что вы получили, 3) почему вы считаете, что результат должен быть другим

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В параметрах функции добавьте атрибут [ordered] для хэш-таблицы $key:

```
$key = [ordered]@{}
```

Подробнее по ссылке [Use PowerShell to Create Ordered Dictionary](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-create-ordered-dictionary/)

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!